# How to avoid the users from seeing the webviews resize to match content?

Tags: android, listview, webview

I have an activity with a number of WebViews. Local html is loaded to them on onCreate() of the activity. How to avoid the users from seeing the webviews resize?

The WebViews are placed in a linearlayout (which is in a scrollview). There are more than 100 of them

As the app starts webviews are loaded with local html. 
However heres what the users see.

1. A list of empty webviews appear as the app starts. They are small in height as they are empty.
2. Then (within milliseconds) the webviews get content and they expand in size to wrapcontent.

I want to avoid the users from seeing this transition. I want them to see (step2) as the first thing they see without seeing the step1.

I tried the onPageFinished of webview with no luck. Therefore I think this problem is not unique to webview.

Comment: you can show progress bar on webview till your pages loading

Comment: i made the whole list invisible at the beginning and made it visible only after the onPageFinished of every webview. But still I saw it. So the problem should be with the resizeing drawing of the views. Not with the loading thing. (it loads in millisecs as local contents)

Comment: Have you tried covering the webview with another view and when webview is loadded then hiding that view?

Comment: I can manage the hiding and showing part. What I cannot do is detecting the event when everything is done and ready for the user